# How to create a type derived from an union type in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, union, keyof

I have the following type

```js
type DataTableCol<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  title: string;
  key: K;
  render?: (value: T[K]) => ReactElement;
};
```

I need to create another type, `DataTableRow<T>`, derived from it. From `type MyData = { name: string; value: number; }`, it will have the following form:

```js
type DataTableRow<MyData> = (DataTableCol<MyData, 'name'> | DataTableCol<MyData, 'value'>)[]
```

It will basically be an array of a new union type, mapped for each keyof T, I want to use generics because this code will be reusable.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type DataTableCol<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  title: string;
  key: K;
  render?: (value: T[K]) => any;
};

type Distribute<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? DataTableCol<T, K> : never;

type DataTableRow<T> = (Distribute<T, keyof T>)[];

type MyData = { name: string; value: number; };

type Foo = DataTableRow<MyData>;
// (DataTableCol<MyData, "name"> | DataTableCol<MyData, "value">)[]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVOAjANhAwge3QHiQBooBpKCAD2AgDsATAZygGsIQcAzKJAPigC8UAN4AoKFGABLYJgBcURsABOU2gHMA3ONbsFpbROV16EZQH4FACgBucdAFcICpAG1SAXQCUg-nFog2gC+2qKgkLBSSqqoDjSEJKT8QuRUNAzMbBzcSFDmsAjIaJi4BMRk-Aq0EDZmoeHQ8IgoGBAASjgA7oTJUFYwUSpSsfHlWVw8vF6uHvXg0ACyIE1wgiJQtHAAts6KQxqaUHaOu7QOW6h1UCGiYfNQAGI4OGsrLZgd3UsrvJpAA)